# Coefficients for the three-dimensional discrete Laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I am trying to numerically solve $u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz} = 0$ using a 27-point stencil, meaning each node in my finite difference domain interacts with every node in a $3 \times 3 \times 3$ cube centered around itself. I have found the coefficients for the two-dimensional 9-point stencil, but I do not know how to generate the coefficients for the 27-point stencil, nor can I find them readily available online. Could someone provide a reference to a paper which uses or derives them, or could someone show me how I might start the derivation process myself?

Comment: While you somewhat describe your problem it is a little hard to figure out what other information you haven't shared (boundary conditions? initial condition? domain?). Further, what type of scheme are you making? Central? Forward? Backward?

Comment: If I'm reading this right -- isn't this given by the (generalized) Kronecker Sum of $L = (I_n \otimes I_n \otimes A) + (I_n \otimes A \otimes I_n) +  (A \otimes I_n \otimes I_n)$ for your n x n matrix A where n is evidently 3 here and $\otimes$ denotes Kronecker Product.

Comment: Since I am not aware of any intuitive way how you can construct the 2D 9-point stencil, I think you have to get your hands dirty and do the Taylor expansion, set up the linear system and solve this.